# What is the range of the most powerful step down DC/DC converters nowadays?

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter, step-down

The team in my lab's company, we want to start using high voltage DC to perform some tests. The electric company can supply us a line of 25kV DC but in reality we would need to chop it to get voltages around 5kV DC. Some managers have been talking to use a resistor divider but we will obviously have energy losses there. That's why I tried to find a DC/DC step down converter but haven't found any...

- What's is the current state of the art of the step down DC/DC converters?
- What other alternatives there are, besides  the resistor divider, to step down such a high DC voltage with less losses?

**Additional info**

In essence, the circuit is based on this schematic (simplified). Basically we can choose to charge up the capacitors up to 800 V with the control unit and then we connect the SPD and allow the circuit to draw as much current as needed. It can reach up to 1800A. The thing is, we want to be able to increase the capabilities of this machine because for these new tests we will need around 1.5kV an possibly more, its true that for this first test the current will have to be around 10A but, in the future, we plan to increase the current capabilities aswell and reach to thousends of amps.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsexxZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PD: Don't take the values of the components too seriusly, I only intend to show the circuit topology.

Comment: How much current do you need at 5kV?  You might be going at this the hard way.

Comment: This looks like a specialized/one-off application, which is probably why you haven't been able to find any DC/DC converters that meet your needs.  You may have to design your own.

Comment: It seems like both you and your managers are way out of your depth here. For your own safely and the safety of others, please find someone local to you who knows how to deal with such high voltages.

Comment: If you need to ask the power company for 25kV DC (every old color TV set has this kind of voltage at mA strength), then you are talking about amounts of power where using a resistive divider would be madness.

Comment: @JRE For now we will probably need around 10 A with 1.2kV but we want to be able to produce kA in the future

Comment: @SteveSh Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @user107063 Exactaly, that's why I'm trying to figure out a more optimal solution.

Comment: Right. Thousands of volts, and thousands of amps. These are serious power levels. The fact that resistor dividers are even mentioned suggests that you guys are in way over your head. Hire or contract someone who has experience with high voltage, high power. Preferably before something burns down or someone gets killed.

Comment: @SantiOspina:  You need to back up all the way to the beginning.  You don't need a DC power line from the utility company for testing surge supressors.  What you need to do first is to find the standards that apply to surge suppressors.  They'll tell you for how long the suppressor has to be able to handle the current (and how much current and voltage.)  It is a pulse, not a continuous rating.  It can be generated from a standard 230V power supply.  You store energy in a capacitor, then discharge it for the pulse.

Comment: A surge suppressor isn't intended to handle hundreds of amperes continuously.  Your power supply doesn't need to do so, either.  Once you find the standards, you'll probably also find that there's (expensive) equipment to do the testing and that there are companies who will do the testing and provide you with a certficate that your devices meet the required standards.  Installing a 25kVDC line from the utility company is simply over the top.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at some pictures of what arc flash can do to a human body before deciding whether or not to roll your own equipment for this.

Comment: @JRE Yes, we actually certify SPD for lighting protection and for that we have impulse current and impusle voltage generators. But we are also starting to implement SPD intended for DC aplications and we are trying to evaluate how to perform the correspondant tests based on the IEC standards. For example we would need to simulate faults on the DC power systems transfered by AC power systems and other combinations (as an example)

Comment: and is true that this fault is going to be for a few miliseconds but the SPD that we willl certificate can be used as overvoltage protection in High voltage DC power systems, hence the hight voltage levels. And about the resitor divider I totaly agree with you, ,thats why I created this question because I imagined that there is certainly a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What's is the current state of the art of the step down DC/DC
> converters?*

Stepping down 25 kV DC to 5 kV DC for laboratory use is out of the question compared to using a power converter that can run from a regular AC supply and deliver 5 kV at several amps. The detail of what you require are really needed before I can give further information.

> *Some managers have been talking to use a resistor divider but we will
> obviously have energy losses there*

There will be energy losses in any conversion method you use. If you only require a few mA then using a resistor divider may be the most economical solution. If you need a few amps it certainly won't be.

> *What other alternatives there are, besides the resistor divider, to
> step down such a high DC voltage with less losses?*

You use a step-up converter and, if necessary, one that is fed from 3-phase in order to reach your power requirements (that you need to state).

Maybe look at [Genvolt capacitor charging power supplies](https://www.genvolt.com/applications/51474d8f69e09/Capacitor-Charging-Power-Supplies). There are other suppliers of this type of equipment of course but, I favour Genvolt because I work for them.

Comment: _"If you only require a few mA then using a resistor divider may be the most economical solution."_ - Maybe... Just to give an idea: if you need 1mA from the divider, you'd want at least 10mA flowing through the divider itself so it can maintain its voltage to within 10%. 10mA @ 25kV dissipates 250W.

Comment: @SantiOspina do you mean you try to put currents of up to 100 amps into an SPD from a 5 kV voltage source? Is your source of the high current a capacitor charged up to 5 kV?

Comment: Hi @AndiAka ! "The detail of what you require are really needed before I can give further information" in our lab we produce short-circuits to surge protective devices (SPD) and we reach up to 1800A (sorry I mistakenly put 100A instead of 1800A)

Comment: In regards to you previous anser: yes beacuse owr sample would need to be conected, for now, at levels in the range of few kV.

Comment: Do you charge a capacitor then discharge it into the SPD. I'm not getting the answers so I'll ask direct. If you don't know, post a circuit of your discharger. You keep mentioning short circuits and that is confusing.

Comment: I edited my original question and added a simple circuit diagram

Comment: @SantiOspina So, how long can you wait for the capacitor to be charged to the target high-voltage (say 5 kV)? Or, how many discharges (into the SPD) per second are you likely to need? Is the capacitor 16 uF? Your picture is a little blurred.

Comment: @SantiOspina if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.